# Keep attachment Sharepoint 2010 when postback

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a custom list with attachment. I'm using SharePoint:AttachmentButton

```
<SharePoint:AttachmentButton runat="server" ID="attc" FieldName="Attachments"/>
```

When form postback, this field can not keep file. I know this is issue of Sharepoint 2010. But i wanna keep this files.

Help me plz

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link , it will proides you some idea about how attachment button works.
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-list-attachment-technical-brief.aspx

As you alrady know that is the something like a bug in Shrepoint 2010.

Still you can give this a try